# Understanding speech recognition of Amazon Alexa and Google Assistant

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, dialogflow-es, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

According to my experience I have found out following outcomes which may not be correct. I want your opinions on that.

- When I design interaction model in Alexa, then Alexa's speech recognition seems to adapt with the change in language model.
- In case of Google Assistant, (I am using dialogflow here) any change in language model is not helping with the speech recognition. It seems to use google's first intuition to resolve speech into text.

Answer (score 2):

If you use entities, then those are passed on to the Assistant platform to help with speech biasing.

Comment: Entities defined in dialogflow too? Cause we can integrate any third party NLP using actions sdk. I don't know if they do some special configuration for dialogflow specifically...

Comment: Yes, your custom entities defined in Dialogflow too. The Actions SDK is specifically designed to let you use your own NLP.